# Map a Responsive Triangle with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, responsive-design, triangular

I'd like to know if there is a way to map a responsible triangle using JavaScript.

Comment: Not clear. What is a `triangle` in your context?

Comment: It's all the types of triangles. I do not want the code by its self, but know how to do it, do you understand?